# Jenkins is not picking up my sloccount.sc file

Tags: jenkins

I have `sloccount.sc` in my workspace which was generated during the build process and is now filled with relevant data. The code for generating it looks like this:

```
sloccount --wide --details workspace/$JOB_NAME > sloccount.sc
```

I also have the `Publish SLOCCount analysis results` checkbox in settings checked which seem to suggest that it will pickup `**/sloccount.sc` but when I after hitting build the `SLOCCount` graph or tab doesn't seem to pick it up.

The Jenkins user is the owner of the `sloccount.sc` file, and clicking the little link under `SLOCCount reports` textfield that says `the workspace root` I end up looking at the directory that has the `sloccount.sc` file.

Any idea what might be going wrong?

Comment: Jenkins is listing the steps it does post-building to collect all the items, is SLOCCount listed there as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you look into your sloccount.sc? What is inside?

It seems to me it should be called like `sloccount --wide --details . > sloccount.sc` since default path for bash scripts is the workspace.

Comment: Works now, thanks! I'm not sure why it wasn't before, I thought I tried that!